# Jenkins Master on Windows - Java settings

Tags: java, windows, jenkins

I'm running a new Jeninks Master instance on Windows (windows server 2012).
The Jenkins master has failed twice in 5 days. the Jenkins instance has about 30 nodes and is not too busy.

I noticed the memory consumption of Jenkins was quite low (400mb) with the default java memory settings in jenkins.xml

I modified the jenkins.xml to `-Xrs -Xmx1536m` and the Java process is not using 515mb of memory.

I tried to set Xmx to a higher value but the Jenkins service would not start.

After the 2nd failure today, I got the same error message below repeated.

The windows server has 8 cores and 16GB memory. Average CPU is <5% and average memory usage is 2GB. Jenkins version is 1.609.3

Any help pointers appreciated....

```
Sep 21, 2015 12:00:48 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(Unknown Source)
at winstone.BoundedExecutorService.scheduleNext(BoundedExecutorService.java:74)
at winstone.BoundedExecutorService.execute(BoundedExecutorService.java:64)
at     org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ExecutorThreadPool.dispatch(ExecutorThreadPool.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager.dispatch(SelectChannelConnector.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.dispatch(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.schedule(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:195)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$1.run(SelectorManager.java:290)
at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution to this. I installed the JDK and used VisualVM to monitor the memory usage for JVM. This showed 32 bit memory boundaries. After a little digging the java.exe that Jenins points to by default in Jenkins_Home/jre/bin is a 32bit version of java. I modified the Jenkins.xml to point to the already installed 64 Jre. This worked fine and was able to modify the Xmx valve to 4G. Jenkins is now running happly using <2gb of memory for the JVM process.

Comment: I had to replace the jre in the default location (in Jenkins\jre) in order to make it work, otherwise I couldn't access the web page after start up.